# Unable to remove ParseException

Tags: java, web-applications, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, parseexception

```
try{
             SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(tm);
                timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

        }
         catch (Exception pe) {
              System.out.println("unexpected exception");
                System.out.println(pe); 
                pe.printStackTrace(); 
            }
```

Console shows "unexpected error"(which is in my catch block). I am trying to convert "tm" which is client-side input date into a timestamp. The value of tm is like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM: SS"(String). But the console keeps on showing Unparseable date. I am new to Java.

Comment: What's the value of the `tm` variable?  Perhaps it doesn't match your format.

Comment: It is like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM: SS" which the user fill through html page

Comment: The value in tm must be of String type and the format must be a valid one. Else this throw a run-time exception.

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava your problem is here "hh" most likely. This is 1-12, not 0-23. Use "HH"

Comment: Still it is showing unparseable date

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please in your question also include the output from `System.out.println(pe);`. It can tell us a whole lot. You may also paste the stacktrace (formatted as code for readability). While in this case the stacktrace may not be essential, it’s a good habit when asking about an error that gives a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String tm = "2019-02-09 07:35:54";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(tm, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This produces the following output:

> 2019-02-09T07:35:54

I discourage the use of `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### JDBC 4.2+

If you thought you needed a `Timestamp` for your database, you probably don’t. Assuming your JDBC driver is up to JDBC 4.2 you can directly give it the `LocalDateTime` object we just produced. For example like:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = yourConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into your_table(your_timestamp_col) values (?);");
    ps.setObject(1, dateTime);
```

### What went wrong in your code?

There are two errors in your format pattern string, `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`:

1. Assuming that the hours in the user input are hour of day from 00 through 23, you need uppercase `HH` to parse them, as LppEdd already said in a comment (lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12 and of course requires that an AM or PM marker is present).
2. Since the user input doesn’t include fraction of second, you should not have `.SSS` in the format pattern (this is probably what caused your exception).

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this out

```
    String tm = "2014-01-01 00:00:00";
    String frontEndFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(frontEndFormat);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(tm, formatter);
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
    //prints 2014-01-01 00:00:00.0
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

You can notice the upper case HH used for hours and the lower case mm used for minutes.

Comment: If one indispensably needs on old-fashioned `Timestamp` for a legacy API that cannot be changed (just now), this is the right solution. Thanks.